# MySQL Query update Table A based on logic test made on Table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a MySQL Query that updates Table A based on logic test made on Table B.

I want to show [visible: yes] only products with discount > 40%

Discount logic test: [100/(old_price/price)] > 40 . The query is for use on PhpMyAdmin (WordPress)

```
Table A (product status)

product_id  visible
1           yes
2           no
3           yes
4           no

Table B (product details)

product_id  meta_key    meta_value
2           price       550
2           old_price   600
1           price       200
1           old_price   400
4           price       300
4           old_price   350
3           price       100
3           old_price   300
```

Comment: What have you tried? You nearly wrote the query here. Also please be careful when tagging. sql server <> mysql.

Comment: what is your expected results.  did you try anything?

Comment: this can be only sql server or mysql not both.  which is it.

Comment: Sorry, this is MySQL query for use on PhpMyAdmin (WordPress). The expected result is: Update "visible" to "yes" only if the product discount is more than 40%. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer Mr. Dhruv Saxena kindly sent me and works perfectly:

```
UPDATE product_status ps
INNER JOIN product_details pd1
    ON ps.product_id = pd1.product_id
    AND pd1.meta_key = 'price'
INNER JOIN product_details pd2
    ON ps.product_id = pd2.product_id
    AND pd2.meta_key = 'old_price'

SET ps.visible = 
             CASE
                WHEN (100/(pd2.meta_value/pd1.meta_value)) > 40.00
                    THEN 'yes'
                ELSE
                    'no'
             END;
```

He even sent me a demo test: http://rextester.com/OWRQZE95139

Answer (score 1):

```
update product_status
set visible = 'yes'
where product_id in ( select product_id, (100/(max(old_price)/max(price))) as discount
                        from ( select product_id, meta_value as old_price, null as price
                                 from product_details
                                where meta_key = 'old_price'
                               union
                               select product_id, null, meta_value
                                 from product_details
                                where meta_key = 'price' ) as checkit
                        where (100/(max(old_price)/max(price)) > 40
                        group by product_id));
```

Comment: Run this on PhpMyAdmin. Had to fix it putting one more ")" closing the penultimate line this way: where (100/(max(deal_price)/max(deal_sale_price)))  > 40. Also fixed the last line this way: group by post_id); Even so, got error: "Invalid use of group function". Thanks!

Comment: In my "visible" column values are 1 or 0 (show/hide). Used "yes" / "no" here for better understanding. I think this isn't a problem.

Comment: Sorry - didn't actually run the code.  And obviously wasn't paying attention to bracket matching in vim.  Very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This might give what you want:

```
select product_status.product_id,
case when (1.00*c.meta_value)/(1.00*b.meta_value) < 0.6 then 1 else 0 end as visible
from product_status
inner join
(select * 
from product_details 
where meta_key = 'old_price') b
on product_status.product_id = b.product_id
inner join
(select * 
from product_details 
where meta_key = 'new_price') c
on product_status.product_id = c.product_id
```

If it does, substitute the appropriate UPDATE statement for the SELECT statement.

Comment: Got syntax error on line 2. Sorry, this is for use on PhpMyAdmin (WordPress). I didn't tell. In my "visible" column values are 1 or 0 (show/hide). Used "yes" / "no" here for better understanding.

Comment: @Eric On line 2 - the 'case when'? I've edited that line. Does it still error? I don't know PhpMyAdmin or what difference that makes.

Comment: Got: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'case when (1.00*c.meta_value)/(1.00*b.meta_value) < 0.6 then 1 else 0 end as off' at line 2". Thanks

Comment: OK. If replacing the 'case when...end' part with e.g. '(1.00*c.meta_value)/(1.00*b.meta_value) as ratio' (without the quotation marks) gives you an output, you just need to Google how to do a 'case when' in your version of SQL and adapt what I have written. Otherwise, I wouldn't know what else to suggest.

Comment: The Query you suggested works when using SELECT, but not with UPDATE. (don't need to replace with your last comment). I'll look for how to use  "case when" on my SQL version. Tell you soon! Thanks!

Comment: "product_status" table has 2 product types (coupon, deal) which are identified on column "offer_type" of the same table. Coupon has not prices value, so the query can't calculate on it. Do you think it's better to specify on line 1 anything like: WHERE offer_type = 'deal' ? (Note: Using SELECT runs perfectly: coupons are not returned, only deals)

Comment: Sounds like you got it sorted. Accepted answer is basically the same, but reveals the completely unnecessary subqueries in my answer...